# How can I scale a 3D Cube while maintaining it's center in WebGL GLSL?

Tags: javascript, three.js, glsl, coordinate-transformation

I have a scale attribute like that I am applying to different instances of a [instance buffered geometry](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/core/InstancedBufferGeometry) in three js. The shader look like this:

```
attribute float scale;

uniform vec3 uMeshPosition;

void main() {
  vec3 pos = position;
  pos.x *= ( uMeshPosition.x - pows.x ) * scale + uMeshPosition.x;
  pos.z *=  ( uMeshPosition.z - pos.z ) * scale + uMeshPosition.z;
  pos.y *=  ( uMeshPosition.y - pos.y ) * scale + uMeshPosition.y;

  gl_Position = projectionMatrix * modelViewMatrix * vec4(pos,1.0);
}
```

[image: position problem]

**Z is the height in my case!!!**

I'd like the scaled cubes to maintain their initial center indicated by the wireframe cube above.

[image: partial solution]

Can scaling applied on all 3 axis be done without calculating and applying scale on the CPU?

Updates:

The way I'm creating the Geometry, normally with multiple cubes, but for this example it will be just one instance:

```
 const createInstancedGeometry = (instanceCount, sizeX = 1, sizeY = 1, sizeZ = 1) => {
  const geometry = new InstancedBufferGeometry()
  geometry.maxInstancedCount = instanceCount

  const shape = new BoxBufferGeometry(0.1 * sizeX, 0.1 * sizeY, 0.1 * sizeZ)
  shape.translate(0, 0.4, 0)

  const data = shape.attributes

  geometry.addAttribute('position', new BufferAttribute(new Float32Array(data.position.array), 3))
  geometry.addAttribute('uv', new BufferAttribute(new Float32Array(data.uv.array), 2))
  geometry.addAttribute('normal', new BufferAttribute(new Float32Array(data.normal.array), 3))
  geometry.setIndex(new BufferAttribute(new Uint16Array(shape.index.array), 1))
  shape.dispose()

  createInstancedAtrributes(geometry, instanceCount)

  return geometry
}
```

This is the way I'm setting up the shader, I'm not using the colors yet.

```
const createShader = () => {
  const uniforms = {
    // uMap: { type: 't', value: null },
    uColor1: { type: 'c', value: new Color(0x961800) }, // red
    uColor2: { type: 'c', value: new Color(0x4b5828) }, // yellow
    uMeshPosition: { type: 'vec3', value: new Vector3(0, 0, 0) },
  }

  const shader = new ShaderMaterial({
    uniforms,
    vertexShader,
    fragmentShader,
    blending: AdditiveBlending,
    transparent: true,
    depthWrite: false,
  })

  return shader
}
```

The constructor for my Particle Fire looks like this:

```
constructor({ sizeX = 1, sizeY = 1, sizeZ = 1 } = {}) {
    const instanceCount = 1
    const geometry = createInstancedGeometry(instanceCount, sizeX, sizeY, sizeZ)
    const material = createShader()

    const mesh = new Mesh(geometry, material)
    mesh.frustumCulled = false

    this.geometry = geometry
    this.material = material
    this.mesh = mesh

    mesh.up = new Vector3(0, 0, 1)
    mesh.position.set(2, 2, 1)
    mesh.rotateX(Math.PI / 2)

    this.instanceCount = instanceCount

    const lineGeo = new EdgesGeometry(geometry) // or WireframeGeometry
    const mat = new LineBasicMaterial({ color: 0xffffff, linewidth: 2 })
    const wireframe = new LineSegments(lineGeo, mat)
    this.mesh.add(wireframe)
  }
```

And the update call:

```
update() {
    const { instanceCount } = this
    const { scale, progress, randoms } = this.geometry.attributes
    const { uMeshPosition } = this.material.uniforms
    uMeshPosition.value = this.mesh.position

    for (let i = 0; i < instanceCount; i += 1) {
      let value = progress.array[i]
      value += 0.025

      if (value > 1) {
        value -= 1
        scale.setX(i, randomValueBetween(0.3, 2, 3))
        // randoms.setX(i, randomValueBetween(0, 1, 3))
      }

      // progress.setX(i, value)
    }


    scale.needsUpdate = true
    // randoms.needsUpdate = true
    // progress.needsUpdate = true
  }
```

I'm adding the object to the scene like this:

```
const pFire = new ParticleFire()
scene.add(pFire.mesh)
```

And updating it in a render loop like this:

```
  pFire.update({ deltaTime })

  renderer.render(scene, cameraController.camera)

  requestAnimationFrame(animate)
```

And `cameraController.camera` is a simple camera controller added to the scene as a child to a 'character' that I move around the scene.

```
  configuredCamera = new PerspectiveCamera(
    75, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 5000,
  )
```

Comment: it seems it's not computed by default for the box geometry

Comment: I'd like to answer that but I don't know how. How can I check the center?

Comment: Updated the question. Thanks for taking the time to look at this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `translate` function of [`THREE.Geometry`](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/core/Geometry) translates each vertex of the mesh. So the mesh it self is displaced and its center is not (0, 0, 0) anymore.

You should set the geoemtry of the instead (`position`). See [`THREE.Object3D`](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/core/Object3D.position).

This means you have to delete `shape.translate(0, 0.4, 0)` and you have to do the whole placement by `geometry.position`.
Then the mesh is not displaced anymore and is placed by the `modelViewMatrix` alone. And the GLS shader code will work:

```
gl_Position = projectionMatrix * modelViewMatrix * vec4(pos * scale, 1.0);
```